# Is subclasing django base classes to intermediate ones a bad idea?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have subclassed ModelForm to an intermediate ModelForm2 to make sure some form elements have certain css classes / widgets and to remove the label suffix.
My question is:
Is this a bad idea since it makes the code less portable in case they drop ModelForm classes?
This is the code:

```
class ModelForm2(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(ModelForm2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields:
            if isinstance(self.fields[field], forms.DateField):
                self.fields[field].format = '%d/%m/%Y'
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class'] = 'date'
                self.fields[field].widget.attrs['type'] = 'text'
```

I'm not looking for opinions, just a solid "best practices" answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is *not* a bad idea, this is very normal 'best practice' Django.

`ModelForm` is a core part of Django, it is pretty unthinkable they would drop it.

Typical Django project will have many sub-classes from Django base classes.

I will often have an app in my project I call `core`, or something similar, where I keep some classes like `BaseModel`, `BaseForm` etc where I have customised some behaviour that I want inherited by all my project's sub-classes.

Comment: Thanks! This made my ground more solid :)